# How to select multiple results into one row with pattern

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I read [Concatenate multiple results into one row](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5526018500346202509) and i don't understand about that.

My table:

```
-----------------
|    P_TABLE    |
-----------------
| P_ID | P_DATA |
|  12  |  AAAA  |
|  15  |  BBBB  |
|  19  |  CCCC  |
-----------------
```

Normally query is `SELECT P.P_ID FROM P_TABLE P` and the result is

```
--------
| P_ID |
--------
|  12  |
|  15  |
|  19  |
--------
```

but, I need result like this

```
---------------
|    P_ID     |
---------------
|  (12,15,19) |
```

How ?

I think this solution may be solve by [Oracle PIVOT](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1#pivot), but I have no idea how to use.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Possible to do via SQL ? or need C# to help about pattern ?

Comment: Do you need those parentheses in the result? Also - do you need to do this for just one column, or for more than one? If it's the latter, you can combine PIVOT with the accepted answer; LISTAGG, like MAX or SUM, is an aggregate function that works perfectly well with PIVOT.

Comment: @mathguy No problem, I use `||` for that i.e. `select '(' || listagg(p_id,',') || ')' ...` , Thank you for your interests. :)

Comment: @mathguy But, I still Interested the PIVOT function, If you post how to, I think it should be helpful for another.

Comment: So, that was the more meaningful question - which you didn't answer. Do you or might you in the future need to do this for more than one column?

Comment: @mathguy Single column only sir.

Comment: Then you don't need PIVOT, JSapkota's solution is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [LISTAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030)

```
select listagg(p_id,',') within group (order by p_id) p_id from p_table;
```

Comment: AWESOME, Thank you so much.

Comment: @TooNDinDarkDevil - Or, if the `p_id` should be ordered by something else (not simply in increasing order of themselves) - for example, if they must be ordered by `p_data`, or perhaps by a timestamp column you didn't show, that can be done too, easily - just change what you "order by" within group.